# AngularFire2 Offline

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, offline, angularfire2

I wanted to know if it's me doing something wrong or if it is the library.

I followed the Ionic Offline Tutorial from AngularFire2 Offline 1 on 1. Then I build the app and it worked, I tought.. until I found this:

when you enter the app in offline mode, and I add my name to a list and close the app, and open it again in offline mode. I am frustrated because my name does not show up in the list, if I then add my name again to the list and close and open it, then again my name is gone... But then when I go online, my name pops up two times. Very strange behavior, in my opinion, this is not really offline?

My question, is there a way to fix this behavior? I want to see the changes that I made while I am offline even when I close the app en restart it again in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Offline` + `Persistence` for that.

`Offline` alone will behave as you are describing.

With `Persistence` however it will behave as you want it.

*Hopefully it helps someone.*